# EMPLOYEE MDB ACCESS GET ERROR 'Message: No value given for one or more required parameters'

Tags: c#, ms-office

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{    
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private string gs_ConnString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
            + "Data Source=YorkProducts.accdb;"
            + "Persist Security Info=False;";

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }    

        private void ClearForm()
        {
            tb_EmpNr.Clear();
            tb_LastName.Clear();
            tb_FirstName.Clear();
            tb_MiddleName.Clear();
            tb_Address.Clear();
            tb_Zip.Clear();
            tb_City.Clear();
            tb_State.Clear();
            tb_Phone.Clear();
            tb_PayLevel.Clear();
            tb_PayGrade.Clear();
            tb_DOH.Clear();
        }//end clear form

        private void GetCityState()
        {
            try
            {
                //create the connection
                string Query = "SELECT City, State " +
                                       " FROM tbl_Zip WHERE Zip=" + "\"" + tb_Zip.Text + "\"" + "";
                OleDbConnection Connection = new OleDbConnection(gs_ConnString);
                OleDbCommand Command = new OleDbCommand(Query, Connection);
                Connection.Open();
                OleDbDataReader Reader;
                Reader = Command.ExecuteReader();
                Reader.Read();
                tb_City.Text = Reader.GetString(0);
                tb_State.Text = Reader.GetString(1);
                Reader.Close();
                Connection.Close();
            }//end try
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Message: " + error.Message,
                    "EMPLOYEE MDB ACCESS GET ZIP ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                    MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }//end catch
        }//end get city state

        private void GetRecFromDatabase(string s_EmpNr)
        {
            try
            {
                //create the connection
                string Query = "SELECT EmpNumber, EmpLastName, EmpFirstName, EmpMiddleName, EmpAddress, EmpZip," +
                                       " EmpPhone, EmpPayLevel, EmpPayGrade, EmpHireDate" +
                                       " FROM tbl_Employee WHERE EmpNumber=" + "\"" + s_EmpNr + "\"" + "";
                OleDbConnection Connection = new OleDbConnection(gs_ConnString);
                OleDbCommand Command = new OleDbCommand(Query, Connection);
                Connection.Open();
                OleDbDataReader Reader;
                Reader = Command.ExecuteReader();
                Reader.Read();
                tb_EmpNr.Text = Reader.GetString(0);
                tb_LastName.Text = Reader.GetString(1);
                tb_FirstName.Text = Reader.GetString(2);
                tb_MiddleName.Text = Reader.GetString(3);
                tb_Address.Text = Reader.GetString(4);
                tb_Zip.Text = Reader.GetString(5);
                tb_Phone.Text = Reader.GetString(6);
                tb_PayGrade.Text = String.Format("{0}", Reader.GetInt32(7));
                tb_PayLevel.Text = String.Format("{0}", Reader.GetInt32(8));
                tb_DOH.Text = String.Format("{0:d}", Reader.GetDateTime(9));
                Reader.Close();
                Connection.Close();
                GetCityState();
            }//end try
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Message: " + error.Message,
                    "EMPLOYEE MDB ACCESS GET ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                    MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }//end catch
        }//end GetRecFromDatabase




        private void b_Clear_Screen_Click_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
            ClearForm();
            tb_EmpNr.Focus();
        }

        private void b_Add_Customer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                //create the connection
                string Query = "INSERT INTO tbl_Employee (EmpNumber, EmpLastName, EmpFirstName, EmpMiddleName, " +
                                                       "EmpAddress, EmpZip, EmpPhone, EmpHireDate, EmpPayLevel, EmpPayGrade)" +
                             "VALUES(" + "\"" + tb_EmpNr.Text + "\"" + ", "      //strings get double quotes
                                       + "\"" + tb_LastName.Text + "\"" + ", "
                                       + "\"" + tb_FirstName.Text + "\"" + ", "
                                       + "\"" + tb_MiddleName.Text + "\"" + ", "
                                       + "\"" + tb_Address.Text + "\"" + ", "
                                       + "\"" + tb_Zip.Text + "\"" + ", "
                                       + "\"" + tb_Phone.Text + "\"" + ", "
                                       + "#" + tb_DOH.Text + "#" + ", "
                                       + tb_PayLevel.Text + ", "
                                       + tb_PayGrade.Text
                                       + ")";
                OleDbConnection Connection = new OleDbConnection(gs_ConnString);
                OleDbCommand Command = new OleDbCommand(Query, Connection);
                Connection.Open();
                OleDbDataReader Reader;
                Reader = Command.ExecuteReader();
                Reader.Close();
                Connection.Close();
            }//end try
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Message: " + error.Message,
                    "EMPLOYEE MDB ACCESS ADD ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                    MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }//end catch
        }

        private void b_Get_Customer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {//get a specific rec
            GetRecFromDatabase(tb_EmpNr.Text);
        }

        private void tb_Zip_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {//get the city and state
            GetCityState();
        }

        private void b_Get_Next_Customer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {//get next rec
            string s_NextRec = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(tb_EmpNr.Text) + 1);
            GetRecFromDatabase(s_NextRec);
        }

        private void b_Update_Customer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {//update the record
            try
            {
                string Query = "UPDATE tbl_Employee SET " +
                                    "EmpLastName =" + "\"" + tb_LastName.Text + "\"" + ", " +
                                    "EmpFirstName =" + "\"" + tb_FirstName.Text + "\"" + ", " +
                                    "EmpMiddleName =" + "\"" + tb_MiddleName.Text + "\"" + ", " +
                                    "EmpAddress =" + "\"" + tb_Address.Text + "\"" + ", " +
                                    "EmpZip =" + "\"" + tb_Zip.Text + "\"" + ", " +
                                    "EmpPhone =" + "\"" + tb_Phone.Text + "\"" + ", " +
                                    "EmpHireDate =" + "#" + tb_DOH.Text + "#" + " " + ", " +
                                    "EmpPayLevel =" + Convert.ToInt32(tb_PayLevel.Text) + ", " +
                                    "EmpPayGrade =" + Convert.ToInt32(tb_PayGrade.Text) +
                               " WHERE EmpNumber =" + "\"" + tb_EmpNr.Text + "\"" + " ";

                OleDbConnection Connection = new OleDbConnection(gs_ConnString);
                OleDbCommand Command = new OleDbCommand(Query, Connection);
                Connection.Open();
                OleDbDataReader Reader;
                Reader = Command.ExecuteReader();
                Reader.Close();
                Connection.Close();
                GetRecFromDatabase(tb_EmpNr.Text);
            }//end try
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Message: " + error.Message,
                                "EMPLOYEE MDB ACCESS ERROR", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                                 MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }//end catch
        }//end update click
    }//end class
}//end namespace
```

This program is supposed to grab data from an access database that I have manually created and place the data into the fields of a form.  I have placed the access database into the debug folder of the project(in visual studio) however I am receiving the error message stated in the title.  I think it is possible that I have the database file in the wrong location?  I have added Microsoft Access 14.0 as a reference and installed the Microsoft Access Database engine for my version of access.  Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

```
string Query = "SELECT City, State FROM tbl_Zip WHERE Zip='" + tb_Zip.Text+"'";
```

**Solution 2:**

```
           //create the connection
            string Query = "SELECT City, State FROM tbl_Zip WHERE Zip=@zip";
            OleDbConnection Connection = new OleDbConnection(gs_ConnString);
            OleDbCommand Command = new OleDbCommand(Query, Connection);
            Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@zip",tb_Zip.Text);
            Connection.Open();
            OleDbDataReader Reader;
            Reader = Command.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: Which line(s) should I replace with your statement?

Comment: @Rew: String query statement.

Comment: I replaced the lines of code with the lines you sent but I got the same error message.  Is it possible that you need the Access file in a specific folder?

Comment: @Rew: your access file should be in current project folder path, otherwise do one thing copy your access file into c drive and give path in your connection string as -> `private string gs_ConnString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
            + "Data Source=C:\\YorkProducts.accdb;"
            + "Persist Security Info=False;";`

Comment: Before I attempted your solution, I noticed that I was attempting to use "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" while I have Microsoft Access 14.0 listed as a reference, could this be the issue?   After changing the 12 to 14, I received the error message that 14.0 is not registered on my machine.  However, 12.0 is not listed under references so I am unable to add that as a reference

Comment: Moving the file to the C drive still produces the same error of no value given for one or more required parameters.

Comment: From the error message, I would say you also need to fix the SQL to use "'" in GetRecFromDatabase, assuming you haven't already. The provider name is correct, i.e. it should still be "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" even though it's Access 14. (FWIW I don't think you need a reference to Access 14.0 in your project if you are just using OLEDB to access the data, but I don't think having the reference will cause problems).